# How to repeat this type of for loop?

Tags: loops

```
for (int i=0; i<oMsg.length(); i = i + interval) {
    work += oMsg.substring(i, i+1); 
}
```

I want to repeat this but only change the int i = part
for example

```
for (int i=0; i<oMsg.length(); i = i + interval) {
    work += oMsg.substring(i, i+1); 
}
for (int i=1; i<oMsg.length(); i = i + interval) {
    work += oMsg.substring(i, i+1); 
}

for (int i=2; i<oMsg.length(); i = i + interval) {
    work += oMsg.substring(i, i+1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the second loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
  for (int i = j; i < oMsg.length(); i += interval) {
    work += oMsg.substring(i, i + 1); 
  }
}
```